# Dynamically Disable Particular Context Menu Item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've added 4 menus in context menu. If during the start context menu item is clicked, how to disable that particular `("Start")` menu item?

```
ContextMenu conMenu1 = new ContextMenu();
public Form1()
{
            InitializeComponent();
    conMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Start", new System.EventHandler(this.Start_Click));
    conMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Pause", new System.EventHandler(this.Pause_Click));
    conMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Resume", new System.EventHandler(this.Resume_Click));
    conMenu1.MenuItems.Add("Stop", new System.EventHandler(this.Stop_Click));
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Functionalities to disable start context menu item
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do like this. Handle the ContextMenu.Opening Event

```
private void conMenu1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    conMenu1.Items[0].Enabled= false;
}
```

Comment: conMenu1.MenuItems[1].Enabled = false;  i added this piece of code in Start_Click , It's working now, Thanks for your help

Comment: @Vignesh why you wanna to add it on `start_click`. You can simpoy disabled it when menu is opening

Comment: My requirement is like once if i clicked the start button or start menu the timer has to start, i don't want the timer to be started oftenly. Once start time is set initially it should be the final one

Comment: +1 conmenu_Opening is a very nice approach! I used `(sender as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl` to get to the calling `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PopUp` event such as

**Declaration**

```
var trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
trayMenu.Popup += MenuOpening;

trayMenu.MenuItems.Add(...);
...
```

**Subscribed Event**

```
private void MenuOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    var cm = sender as ContextMenu;

    if (cm != null)
         cm.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
}
```