# Hide an option from right click Windows context menu when two files are selected

Tags: c#, windows, registry, contextmenu, regedit

I have added an option manually in windows right click context menu when we right click on files 
Ex -: **move to** option added

I need to remove the option **move to** when more than one file is selected

By using register entry I have added an option

Kindly suggest to hide the option when more than 1 file is selected

Comment: Is context menu under your control? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357598/4123703) should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Disable Particular Context Menu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357560/dynamically-disable-particular-context-menu-item)

Comment: Hi Louis go,  Am asking for windows right click context menu 

Comment: You didn't specify about where is it. If you mean right click on file explorer, you shall ask at SuperUser. My only thought is blocking command if there is more than one argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add MultiSelectModel = Single in your registry.